# type parameter t has incompatible upper bounds: view and fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I like to get my fragment of my Activity, but i got the error:

> type parameter t has incompatible upper bounds: view and fragment

by `findViewById(R.id.f_instruction)` in my MainActivity.
I hope you can help me.

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Fragment f_instruction;
public static void closeFragment() {
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    f_instruction = findViewById(R.id.f_instruction);
}
```

}

XML of Activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/f_instruction"
        android:name="e.marco.gymdiary.first_fragment"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="732dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't get fragment by getViewById() method. the correct way for doing this is :

if you are in activity:

```
Fragment fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
```

if you are in fragment:

```
Fragment fragment=getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
```

also this is how to get fragment manager using context (useful if you are in adapter for example)

```
((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. this helped me fix the problem:

1. Go to your "activity_main.xml"
2. Right-click -> Refactor -> Rename (or use SHIFT + F6)
3. Rename your layout to "activity_main2.xml" for example
4. Rename this file back to the original "activity_main.xml"